# C errors with method

Tags: c, incompatibletypeerror

I have the following code:

```
#define MIDTERM_PERCENTAGE 40
#define FINAL_PERCENTAGE 60
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array)[0]))

struct student 
{
     char name[20];
     int  midterm;
     int  final;
     int  grade;
}

int calcGrade(struct student s) {
    int midterm = (s.midterm * MIDTERM_PERCENTAGE)/100;
    int final = (s.final * FINAL_PERCENTAGE)/100;
    int grade = midterm + final;
    return grade;
}
```

And I'm getting these errors:

```
student.c:13: two or more data types in declaration of `calcGrade'
student.c: In function `calcGrade':
student.c:17: incompatible types in return
```

I do also have a header file that has the following declaration:

```
int calcGrade(struct student s);
```

However, I do not see my errors. I thought maybe it was an issue with my division but since it gives me no error on setting grade=midterm+final I don't see why I have an issue with my return type.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot a semicolon after the end of the struct definition.